# Using on.exit inside the function callback of exec

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec, exit, child-process

I have the javascript code, which runs exec, something like

```
exec('binary with argument', function(error, stdout,stderr)
{

// Calls a callback function if error is encountered
}
```

I would also like to use the exit status of that binary to be sent to the callback function above. The way it is generally done is

```
child.on("exit", function (code) {
  console.log("exit:", code)
})
```

How could I integrate the above exit utility inside exec error handler so I can catch the return error code and pass it to the callback function?

Comment: Are you talking about a nodejs child process or what?

Comment: Yes right...nodejs's child_process exec and on.('exit', function(code))

Comment: So, what is your problem combining these two snippets and calling the same callback function from both handlers?

Comment: When exec is initially called and it returns an error, I pass the stderr out to user defined callback. I tried using this code inside the first snippet, but it does not return anything but it does return the correct code if used outside. How do I modify the second snippet so it does return correct code when used inside the first snippet.

Comment: Don't use it inside the first snippet? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: coz I need the exit status of the binary so i can return it back to user defined callback in the first snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need the exit status of the binary so i can return it back to user defined callback in the first snippet.

According to [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), you don't need to listen for the `exit` event to do that:

> *The callback gets the arguments `(error, stdout, stderr)`. On success,
>   `error` will be `null`. On error, `error` will be an instance
>   of `Error` and `error.code` will be the exit code of the child
>   process, and `error.signal` will be set to the signal that terminated
>   the process.*